# Getting same result for all predictions in cnn

Tags: python, image-classification, cnn

This is my first time training a model in cnn and predicting results but I am getting same value for images I have input. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, 
GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU 
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
classifier=Sequential()
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train/=255
X_test/=255
number_of_classes = 10
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, number_of_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, number_of_classes)
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,input_shape= 
(28,28,1),activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=256,activation='relu'))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=10,activation='softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=            
['accuracy'])
gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=8, width_shift_range=0.08,         
shear_range=0.3, height_shift_range=0.08, zoom_range=0.08)

test_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = gen.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=64)
test_generator = test_gen.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=64)
classifier.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=60000, epochs=1, 
                validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps=10000)
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("pitrain.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # grayscale
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
#threshold
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 13) # dilate
im2,contours, hierarchy =             
cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
# get contours
# for each contour found, draw a rectangle around it on original image
for contour in contours:

# get rectangle bounding contour

[x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
# discard areas that are too large

if h>300 and w>300:

    continue
# discard areas that are too small

if h<40 or w<40:

    continue
# draw rectangle around contour on original image

cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)
image.shape
image=image[:,:,:1]
newimg = cv2.resize(image,(28,28))
img.shape
img = np.reshape(newimg,[1,28,28,1])
cv2.imshow("screen",img)
classifier.predict(img)
```

The output I am getting is array of zeros with 1 at third position.
This is where I copied the contour part from https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-extract-a-particular-object-from-images-using-OpenCV

Epoch is equal to 1 because I only wanted to test my model and still I got **accuracy of above 99%**

Comment: What does `pitrain.png` look like?

Comment: I have tried 7,1 and 8

Comment: Can I see a picture of it?

Comment: http://phobia.wikia.com/wiki/Heptaphobia this is the 7 I took as input

Comment: Right now I don't have enough reputation points to post image

Comment: Why are you only training for one epoch? and is the 99% accuracy on the validation/test set or training set?

Comment: Because I only wanted to test my model and the accuracy is on both sets

Comment: I am really doubtful about the reshaping of image along with channels part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I changed your model to simplify the training for example's sake. I will go through the example in detail below. When you feed a value from a different distribution to your model you are always at risk of misclassification. For example, your model was trained using handwritten numbers, thus it is not surprising for the model to missclassify numbers that are typewritten. Of course a deeper more complex model could do this.

---

## Getting the data

The MNIST data is of size 28 by 28. We will convert these values to floating point values and then normalize them to the range 0 to 1. We will also determine that we have 10 output classes.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras import backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

# The known number of output classes.
num_classes = 10
# Input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28
```

Next we need to reshape the data such that it matches with the Tensorflow framework which we will be using under the hood of Keras. This requires that the instances be the first dimension and it also requires a channels dimension as the last one. thus for the MNIST data we need to have $(6000, 28, 28, 1)$.

```
# Channels go last for TensorFlow backend
x_train_reshaped = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
x_test_reshaped = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

Then we will bin the outputs into one-hot-encoded vectors

```
# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices. This uses 1 hot encoding.
y_train_binary = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test_binary = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

Let's build our simple model, you can add more layers to this to make it more robust

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Let's train our model

```
epochs = 4
batch_size = 128
# Fit the model weights.
model.fit(x_train_reshaped, y_train_binary,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test_reshaped, y_test_binary))
```

This should yield about 98.75% on the validation set. This is pretty good and should be enough to test some new data using this set.

---

## Validating results using MNIST

Let's pass through a few random values from the MNIST dataset to see if they get rightfully classified by our model. Note how I set the dimensionality of the data. The instance dimension must exist even if we only have a single instance to predict as well as the channel dimension

```
ix = 0

plt.imshow(X_test[ix,:,:,0], 'gray')
plt.show()

temp = np.zeros((1,28,28,1))
temp[0,:,:,0] = X_test[ix,:,:,0]

model.predict_classes(temp)
```

[image]

> array([7], dtype=int64)

Ok so that worked! Let's try another one `ix = 100`!

[image]

> array([6], dtype=int64)

That worked as well!

---

## Validating the model on novel data

The image you sue has to match stylistically with the ones in the MNIST data set. Ideally they should be of the same distribution. The image you provided luckily gets correctly classified but it should be noted that this may not be the case for other numbers that are typewritten. If you want your algorithm to detect these then you should really train with typewritten numbers as well as handwritten numbers.

```
from skimage.transform import resize

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

im = plt.imread("7 type.jpg")
im = rgb2gray(im)
im = resize(im, (28, 28))

plt.imshow(im[:,:], 'gray')
plt.show()

temp = np.zeros((1,28,28,1))
temp[0,:,:,0] = im

model.predict_classes(temp)
```

[image]

> array([7], dtype=int64)

## Validating on hand drawn numbers

More realistically would be to use hand drawn numbers since that is what we used to train. I just drew this one using Paint.

[image]

> array([8], dtype=int64)

[image]

> array([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjZeD.png), dtype=int64)